# How to store property element in NSDictionary or show in label

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite

My application has a Facebook login module. This will store all the users list in sqlite database and show the list of all user's name in other TableViewController.

I wants that when I click on any cell of user's name then the curresponding records show on other `ViewController`.

I used a property to fetch the record from `TableViewController`  to `ViewController` and use push segue in it. So I have fetched the username and his email-ID. Now i want to show it in labels. How can I show it in labels.

When I used `NSLog("user details %@", self.propertyName);`
I got `user details == {email = "sunil1234523@gmail.com"; name = "Sunil";}`
However, it's not shown on labels.

How can I show username and email ID in different labels.

Can I store it in the `NSDictionary` and then show it. How can I store these in `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take an property variable `NSDictionary` in 2nd viewcontroller and use it like this

In 1st viewcontroller add this code, whenever u want to push the data to second viewcontroller

`secondVCObj.propertyDict = userDetailsDict; //since userDetailsDict is a dictionary.`

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondVCObj animated:YES];`

the dictionary is moved to second viewcontrollers property dictionary and there u can set the text to the labels like this

`userNameLabel.text = [userDetailDict valueForKey:@"name"];`

`emailLabel.text = [userDetailDict valueForKey:@"email"];`

thats it. Happy coding

Comment: Thank you i can do it with your help